# Jquery-ui transfer effect misses target

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jsfiddle to show what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/n9bSC/3/

The jsfiddle works well and does not demonstrate the bug.

In my actual code, the transfer finishes directly *below* the target (instead of directly *at* the target).

I've tried removing the float, adding various "position" styles, etc.

Any thoughts on what could be causing the behavior that I've described?

Comment: your DOM structure of your actual code could have a offset that the ui code isn't properly taking into account. Do you have positioned DOM on the way up the DOM tree?

Comment: I now see that this seems to be happening _anywhere_ I do a transfer. (Any page of my site, any origin element, any target element.)  The transfer finishes 15 or so pixels too low.

Comment: Could you provide us with a link to a page on your site for us to look at?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I also tried upgrading jquery-ui to 1.9.0 and removing all other js, and that didn't help. I'm thinking there must be a CSS issue somewhere, but I haven't been able to find anything suspicious.

Comment: If I strip out all CSS other than the transfer class, it hits the target. I guess now I need to comb through 8,500 lines of CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand this, but I think the problem is fixed.

Our CSS had:

```
body{
  position: relative;
}
```

So I now change that to "inherit" on the page where I'm doing the jquery-ui transfer effect.

Then, I use conditional CSS for only IE7 to do this:

```
.joyride-tip-guide {    
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

(I'm using [Joyride](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) and noticed that changing the body position messed up the Joyride tour step positioning for Internet Explorer 7.)

Comment: I finally noticed that the `body{position: relative;}` comes from the Joyride CSS.  They shouldn't have done that.

Comment: Thanks i had the same problem using Foundation framework by Zurb. They are using the same CSS rule which messes up the `$.transfer()` effect.